# cleft and pseudo cleft sentences(All (that) I did was **touch** the window, and it broke.)

Tags: cleft-constructions

Why is the following example (A) correct as a cleft sentence, but not sentence (B)?

As I have learned, we can only use 'pronoun, noun, gerund, or infinitive', not the base form of verb (*help*) after noun clause. I get confused.

A "All (that) I did was **touch** the window, and it broke."

B "What makes me feel happy is **help** the poor."

---

Are these following sentences correct grammatically and logically?

All (that) I did was (to) touch the window, and it broke.

All (that) I did was touch the window, and it broke.

All (that) I did was touching the window, and it broke.

---

What makes me feel happy is to help the poor.

What makes me feel happy is helping the poor.

What makes me feel happy is  help the poor.

Comment: With "do" pseudo-cleft sentences the -ing form will only be possible if "do" is in the progressive form: "All I was doing was touching the window."

Comment: Your examples commencing with "All"- are not  genuine pseudo clefts, though their structure is related.

Answer (score 3):

Because the bare infinitive **help** is not understood to be a nominal (which goes with **what I like**) but an *action*. *What I want **to do** is help the poor*.  *What makes me happy is **to** help|helping the poor.*

I like look out the window. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

I like looking out the window. <sup>grammatical</sup>

I like to look out the window. <sup>grammatical</sup>

Cleft:

What I like is look out the window.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

What I like is looking out the window. <sup>grammatical</sup>

What I like is to look out the window. <sup>grammatical</sup>

Normal: I touched the window.
Cleft: What I did was touch the window.

**The predicate complement of the cleft  must supply either a nominal or an action *according to the needs of the verb in the cleft*.**

Here, that verb is **did**, and it is looking for an action.  When **did** has the meaning "performed an action" it wants an action complement. The bare infinitive is an action:

I did shop. <sup>grammatical</sup>
I did eat.  <sup>grammatical</sup>
I did play. <sup>grammatical</sup>
I did sky. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Thus:

What I did was **touch** the window. <sup>grammatical</sup>

What I did was **to touch** the window. <sup>ungrammatical [some might say marginal]</sup>

What I did was **touching** the window. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: Is your following explanation true about "All (that)"  or it is only true about "What" ?                                                                                            Because the bare infinitive help is not understood to be a nominal (which goes with what) but an action.

Comment: All I said was lie. or All I said was to lie. or All I said was lying.

Comment: "All that" alone is not enough.  **All that I want** and **all that I did** take different predicate complements.  The verb is important.  "All I *said*" has its own complicated licensing.

Comment: Can I say? "All that I like to buy is books". Could you please give me an example that we can use 'noun, pronoun or infinitive or gerund', not 'base verb' after 'All'?

Comment: Please supply a verb, not just "all".

Comment: @MickeyMouse All I brought with me was this pen

Comment: Please consider the following sentence: "I touched the window, and it broke." Now, Cleft sentence: "All I did was to touch the window, and it broke."  But in original sentence, we don't have "to touch", but we have "touch". I confused as I don't know when we have to use 'gerund, infinitive' when 'base verb'.

Comment: I will enlarge upon the answer.

Comment: Thanks teacher. I really appreciate your help. Sorry taking up too much of your time .this was good point :The predicate complement of the cleft must supply either a nominal or an action according to the needs of the verb in the cleft.

Answer (score 1):

Cleft sentences and *Wh*-Cleft sentences have different forms and different rules. They don't work the same way, even though they're often used for the same purposes -- to point out the important part of a sentence.

There are several different kinds of cleft sentences, but all of them isolate some aspect of the sentence in a special construction, on one side of a special word that's inserted by the clefting rule to separate the important part from the identification part. It's called the fulcrum of cleavage (boldfaced below):

- *I ordered a chocolate malt ==> It was a chocolate malt **that** I ordered.*
  An *It*-Cleft

*It*-Cleft sentences have a dummy *it is/was* followed by the extracted item with a restrictive relative clause identifying it. The relative pronoun (*that* in the example above) is the fulcrum of cleavage. Note that these sentences are not reversible, like *Wh*-Clefts.

- *I ordered a chocolate malt ==> What I ordered **was** a chocolate malt.*
  A *Wh*-Cleft

*Wh*-cleft sentences have an embedded question subordinate clause on one side of a form of auxiliary *be* that acts as a fulcrum (*was* in the example above). Since the fulcrum forms an equational sentence, *Wh*-cleft sentences are reversible in most cases:

- *I ordered a chocolate malt ==> A chocolate malt **was** what I ordered .*
  Another *Wh*-Cleft

As far as the complements are concerned, clefts like *What/All I **did** was ...* should be followed by an infinitive clause *what/all I did was (to) touch it*, with or without *to*, because *do* takes an infinitive complement. But clefts like *What I **like** is ...* can be followed by a gerund clause *what I like is touching it* because *like* can take a gerund complement. *Like* can also take an infinitive (*I like reading/to read*), so *what I like is to touch it* is also OK.

Basically, the kind of complement clause is governed by the verb, not by what construction the verb occurs in. Verbs determine almost everything.

Comment: Thanks for your help and informative information. When we use 'All-Cleft' , where do we have to use 'that'? All (that) I did was touch the window, and it broke or All that I did was that touch the window, and it broke or All  I did was touch the window, and it broke. Why do we use 'that' immediately after 'all'? Is it kind of that-clause or not? I don't know where I should put 'that'.For example in the sentence 'It   is a pity
that he is no longer with us.' I know where I should use 'that' but in All-cleft it is confusing.

Comment: It's a relative clause, so _that_ can be deleted whenever it's allowed in a relative -- i.e, whenever it's not the subject of the relative clause. _All I did was ..._ and _All that I did was ..._ are both OK because _that_ isn't the subject of _did_. _All that happened was ..._ is OK, but **not** *_All happened was ..._.

Comment: Are these sentences correct?

All that I need is  to study hard.
All that I need is a good meal.
All that I need is that I should improve my English.
All that I need to do is play guitar at the moment.
All that I like is going swimming now.
All that I like is to go swimming now.
All that I have to remember is that she is so dangerous.
All that I have difficulty is (in) solving the puzzle.
These two are confusing:
All that I did is describing ALL.
All that I did is to describe or describe ALL.

Comment: Some are and some aren't. Why do you need to know?

Comment: I want to know how much I 've learned this type of grammar.I wrote all of them  by myself.

Comment: "Clefts like *What/All I **did** was* ... should be followed by an infinitive clause ... because *do* takes an infinitive complement." -- Then what is it that makes this sentence grammatical: "All they're doing is rationalising ther failures"? Also, is it known what factors decide whether the infinitive clause licensed by *do* has a bare or a marked infinitive?

Comment: _Rationalizing their failures_ is not a complement of _doing_ in that sentence; that's `Act` _do_, not auxiliary _do_. It has no complement clause.

Comment: How can we tell? That the *rationalise*-clause in "What/all he did is rationalise their failures" is a complement of the verb *DO*, whereas the *rationalising*-clause in "What/all he's doing is rationalising their failures" is *not*? Also, what does "Act" in "Act *do*" stand for?